# Error (Kernel died, restarting) Using pd.to_datetime with date containing +01:00

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

When using this function with a date containing a tz difference suffix (e.g. `2017-07-17T20:15:03.597144+01:00`) the kernal dies before executing any code.

If I remove the +01:00 the script runs error free.

The value of the "Pendulum Timestamp" (`pdts`) is `2017-07-17T20:19:14.508636+01:00`

System Setup Windows 10/ Spyder 3.1.2 / Python 3.6 / Pandas 0.20.3. I tried updating Pandas to 0.20.3 but the kernal still dies.
Is this a case of RTFM or a bug? Thanks

```
    import pendulum as pendulum
    import pandas   as pd

    pendulum_timestamp = pendulum.now() 

    pdts = pendulum_timestamp

    pen_timestamp = pd.to_datetime(pdts)
```

Output of "print(pd.show_versions())" as requested by MaxU

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.6.0.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 10
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.20.3
pytest: 3.0.5
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 27.2.0
Cython: 0.25.2
numpy: 1.12.1
scipy: 0.19.0
xarray: None
IPython: 6.0.0
sphinx: 1.5.1
patsy: 0.4.1
dateutil: 2.6.0
pytz: 2017.2
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.2.0
tables: 3.2.2
numexpr: 2.6.2
feather: None
matplotlib: 2.0.2
openpyxl: 2.4.1
xlrd: 1.0.0
xlwt: 1.2.0
xlsxwriter: 0.9.6
lxml: 3.7.2
bs4: 4.5.3
html5lib: None
sqlalchemy: 1.1.5
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.9.4
s3fs: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: 0.4.0
None
```

Comment: can you post an output of `print(pd.show_versions())`?

Comment: MaxU thank you for your response, I have included the pd,show.versions in the original post as it was too large for the comments section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cast the Pendulum object to its string representation, as `pd.to_timestamp()` doesn't expect a Pendulum object:

```
In [91]: import pendulum

In [92]: pdts = pendulum.now()

In [93]: type(pdts)
Out[93]: pendulum.pendulum.Pendulum

In [94]: pd.to_datetime(str(pdts))   # NOTE: pay attention at `str()`
Out[94]: Timestamp('2017-07-17 20:58:08.995228')

In [95]: pdts
Out[95]: <Pendulum [2017-07-17T22:58:08.995228+02:00]>

In [98]: str(pdts)
Out[98]: '2017-07-17T22:58:08.995228+02:00'

In [99]: type(str(pdts))
Out[99]: str
```

Comment: The string representation works well on my script. I appreciate your help and for the helpful updates to my post.

Comment: @Bass, glad i could help :)